# How to remember last submitted form value, javascript

Tags: javascript, client-side

I have a form with more then 20 fields (text, select, textarea and radio). How can I make the browser remember the submitted values using javascript? I know I can do it in php using `$_SESSION`. But I need to do it in javascript or a client side language. So that if a user enters wrong information, and comes back to the form again, they don't need to re-enter the values again. Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?

Comment: set a cookie with the value you want to store

Answer (score 2):

You could use cookies! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

Ñam ñam :)

Comment: I like this option because it's so simple and will work in every browser. Also, if you're using jQuery, [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) makes it really easy to set and get.

Comment: I thought you liked because I said ñam ñam. Om nom nom cookies!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at using HTML5 Local Storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html. You can't achieve what you're asking with just javascript, because when you visit a new page after submitting the form, all of the local javascript data is gone. You have to store it some way, with either PHP, Local Storage, or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support there are two new objects for storing data locally in HTML5.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Looks like support goes back to IE8.

I created this simple test.  Seems to work ok.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function dotest(){
            var input = document.getElementById('test');
            if( localStorage.test ){
                input.value = localStorage.test;
            }

            input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
                localStorage.test = input.value;
            }, false);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="dotest()">
    <input type="text" id="test">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

could store it in app.locals or res.locals. if you need to persist the data over a longer period of time mongoDB

here is an example of how i use locals so i can store a value, while i grab another one from a different view and then throw them both into a database.

```
    //route to receive the driver name
    app.post('/newdriver', function(req, res){
               app.locals.myVar1 = req.body.newDriver;
       console.log(app.locals.myVar1);
       res.redirect('/newdriverlist')
     });
```